# How to achieve Vim style case sensitive auto completion in emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, case-sensitive

For example, in Vim, if current buffer contains a word "Random", and I type "random" then Ctrl-n, it will be changed to "Random".

But in emacs, it says 'No dynamic expansion for "random" found'.

Is there anyway I can achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you are attempting to expand the word. I'll assume you are useing `dabbrev-expand` (**`M-/`**) or `dabbrev-completion` (**`M-C-/`**).

If you are not, then try just setting variable **`case-fold-search`**, which is the main variable that controls case-sensitivity.  Consult the Emacs manual for more information about controlling case-sensitivity. In the manual, use **`i`** to find index entries that start with `case`, such as these:

```
  case conversion
  case in completion
  case-fold-search 
  case-replace
  case-sensitivity and completion
  case-sensitivity and tags search
```

Assuming that you are using dabbrev:

See variables `dabbrev-case-fold-search` and `dabbrev-case-replace`.  Use `C-h v` to see their documentation:

> **`dabbrev-case-fold-search`** is a variable defined in `dabbrev.el`.
>
> Its value is `case-fold-search`
>
> This variable can be risky when used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Control whether dabbrev searches should ignore case.
>
> A value of `nil` means case is significant.
>
> A value of `case-fold-search` means case is significant if `case-fold-search` is `nil`.
>
> Any other non-`nil` version means case is not significant.
>
> You can customize this variable.

---

> **`dabbrev-case-replace`** is a variable defined in `dabbrev.el`.
>
> Its value is `case-replace`
>
> This variable can be risky when used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Whether dabbrev applies the abbreviations's case pattern to the expansion.
>
> A value of `nil` means preserve the expansion's case pattern.
>
> A value of `case-replace` means preserve it if `case-replace` is `nil`.
>
> Any other non-`nil` value means modify the expansion
>   by applying the abbreviation's case pattern to it.
>
> This variable has an effect only when the value of
>   `dabbrev-case-fold-search` specifies to ignore case.
>
> You can customize this variable.

---

Update after your comment here -

I think you're saying that you want to "complete" or "expand" your input `random` to `Random`.  IOW, you want to clone the case from what's already in the buffer. I don't think that dabbrev works that way.

However, standard library `completion.el` (included with Emacs), which provides also a dabbrev-like behavior option, does at least provide case coercion based on your input (i.e., the other way around).  Here is what the library Commentary says:

```
STRING CASING
 Completion is string case independent if case-fold-search has its
 normal default of T.  Also when the completion is inserted the case of the
 entry is coerced appropriately.
 [E.G.  APP --> APPROPRIATELY     app --> appropriately
        App --> Appropriately]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I have tried these variabels with different values. I can get correct completion using dabbrev-expand after "rando", but not "random". Please note the word is complete now, is it possible just to auto complete the case? My current variables: case-fold-search t, dabbrev-case-fold-search t, dabbrev-case-replace nil, case-replace t